# Loading and changing iFrame 'src' from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, src

I have a page with an iFrame and four links to native files that each appear correctly within the iFrame when summoned. I've done this with straight HTML. The problem is that when I land on the page initially I have an empty iFrame until I click any of the links.

Not only would it be nice to have the iFrame populated with the first link upon arrival, but it would be a real bonus if there was a way to arrive at this page with any other of the remaining links appearing, if in fact that's the content someone came looking for. For example, if I place anchors for my four links on another page, it would be ideal if someone could select the second item and find it populating the iFrame upon arrival at my-iFrame-page.php.

I'm not opposed to using jQuery nor javascripting of any kind, but I'm afraid that for a scripting novice, it's important that I understand the syntax. I'd be over the moon if someone could post a working example that achieves what I'm after.

Comment: what server-side technologies are available to you? PHP? .NET? anything?  If not, then JS is likely your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `src=""` attribute for the iframe which will set the default page.

> For example, if I place anchors for my four links on another page, it would be ideal if someone could select the second item and find it populating the iFrame upon arrival at my-iFrame-page.php.

Needless to say, if you have a preceding page which links to that which contains the iframe, you can pass the url selected as a parameter in the request to the iframe page and then parse it into the attribute with PHP.

---

For simplicity's sake, let's imagine that you have two pages: sourcepage.php and framepage.php. sourcepage.php contains a form with four radio buttons plus a submit button which submits to framepage.php. The radio buttons are all part of the same set, and have four values--as per your comment "Apples", "Bananas", "Cherries" and "Peaches". The Apples radio has a value of 1, Bananas 2 and so on. Each radio has the name "page".

What this means is that when you submit the form, on sourcepage.php you need the following code

```
<?php
    $pageIndex = $_GET["page"];
    $pageUrl = "";

    switch ($pageIndex)
    {
        case "1":
            $pageUrl = "apples.html";
            break;
        case "2":
            $pageUrl = "bananas.html";
            break;
        // And so on...
    }
?>

<!-- And then later... -->

<iframe src="<?php echo $pageUrl; ?>"></iframe>
```

Comment: How would I do this, please?  For example, if the iFrame page is called iFramePage.php where I've set the iframe src="link1", then how do I create a URL that accesses iFramePage.php with link2 appearing in the iFrame (and no need to select it from among the anchors I've listed)?  Thanks sincerely.

Comment: You need to pass the URL as either a GET or POST parameter, or at the very least an indicator to the URL. For example, have a link to iFramePage.php?frame=2 and then in iFramePage.php process the $_GET parameter ['frame'] using a switch case statement where the value "2" is mapped to "link2", which is inserted into the frame's src element.

Comment: Oh, man, sounds great.  I just don't know how to write this: "... in iFramePage.php process the $_GET parameter ['frame'] using a switch case statement where the value "2" is mapped to "link2", which is inserted into the frame's src element."  So far I've bluffed my way through without any javascript.

Comment: You would write that in with PHP. You need to indicate to the receiving page which link you wish to display, and then do a <?php echo (link) ?> into the src="" part of the frame.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the links, if placed on anotherpage.php would be:

<a href="iFramePage.php?frame=1">Apples</a>
<a href="iFramePage.php?frame=2">Bananas</a> 
<a href="iFramePage.php?frame=3">Peaches</a> 
<a href="iFramePage.php?frame=4">Cherries</a>

And then on iFramepage.php, I have:

<iframe id="iframe" src="<?php echo (link) ?>" name="eyeFrame" width="960" height="700"></iframe>

I haven't actually tried this because I'm fairly sure I have something wrong.

Comment: You need to brush up on your PHP a bit. You are on the right track with your links but on your page with the frame (iFramePage.php) you need to parse the "frame" values into a url. The "frame" variable will be stored in $_GET["frame"], so in iFramePage.php you need to do a switch case statement on that variable to map it to a url. For example case "1" might return a url "/mypage1.html". You then take that url and put it in your src attribute of the iframe.

Comment: Yes, but how?  Let's say the four pages are apples.html, bananas.html, peaches.html, and cherries.html.  I realize that there needs to be a way for an external link to target one of these, but I have no idea how to code this. There will be a specific syntax, and it has to be right.  I don't know what that syntax is, and I haven't been able to find it.  For now I just need to find someone who's willing to show me, and that's why I'm here.

Comment: I have updated my answer. All you are doing is inserting a variable into the page just as you would the current date, the name of the currently logged-in user etc. except that here it is going into an attribute. I would recommend that you take a look at this book http://www.amazon.com/dp/1449319262 which will help you learn the fundamentals of web development in PHP because you are going to run into problems like this all the time as you continue developing. I would, however, appreciate a +1 on my answer if you would be so kind ;).

Answer (score 0):

Use JS to get an URL paramater, and ofcourse add a paramater to the links in your footer. Assuming your iframe has id="iframe", this does the trick :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        function get_url_param(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
            var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
            var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
            if (results == null) {
                return "";
            } else {
                return results[1];
            }
        }

        if (get_url_param('show') == '') {
            $('#iframe').attr('src', 'wall-structures.php'); // Setting your default page....
        } else {
            $('#iframe').attr('src', get_url_param('show') + '.php');
        }

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="portfolio.php?show=wall-structures">Wall & Structures</a><br />
    <a href="portfolio.php?show=ovens-barbecues">Ovens & Barbecures</a><br />
    <a href="portfolio.php?show=pillars-arches">Pillars & Arches</a><br />
    <a href="portfolio.php?show=stairs-retaining-walls">Stairs & Retaining Walls</a><br />

    <iframe id="iframe"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

If you don't want to use JS, it can also be done in pure PHP:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['show'])) {
        $iframe_src = $_GET['show'] . '.php';
    } else {
        $iframe_src = 'somedefaultpage.php';
    }

?>


<a href="portfolio.php?show=wall-structures">Wall & Structures</a><br />
<a href="portfolio.php?show=ovens-barbecues">Ovens & Barbecures</a><br />
<a href="portfolio.php?show=pillars-arches">Pillars & Arches</a><br />
<a href="portfolio.php?show=stairs-retaining-walls">Stairs & Retaining Walls</a><br />

<iframe src="<?php echo $iframe_src; ?>"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for this and for your patience.  It does appear that the javascript above only provides for one of the four pages that a visitor might select.  How do I make it work for any of the four?

Comment: I've edited the script to work like that now. Now the javascript is used to listen for click events on any elements with class="iframe-link". So any links to wish to open in your iframe, you can assign the class 'iframe-link'. If you do not wish to use jQuery for this, you could also just write <a href="mylink.html" target="iframe">My link</a> (the target depends on the id attribute of your iframe!).

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you mean by "For example, if I place anchors for my four links on another page, it would be ideal if someone could select the second item and find it populating the iFrame upon arrival at my-iFrame-page.php."??

Comment: I've coded four links that reference each of the native pages that are called to the iFrame like this:<div> 
<p><a href="apples.php" target="eyeFrame">Apples</a></p>
<p><a href="bananas.php" target="eyeFrame">Bananas</a></p>
<p><a href="peaches.php" target="eyeFrame">Peaches</a></p>
<p><a href="cherries.php" target="eyeFrame">Cherries</a></p>
</div>
<iframe id="iframe" src="apples.php" name="eyeFrame" width="960" height="700"></iframe> I'd like to place the links elsewhere on the site and open the iFrame page at any specific one, not necessarily at apples.php, which is what happens currently.

Comment: Still not sure on the purpose of the iframe. If you wish to dynamically change your iframe src relative to a specific site, you need to pass a variable in your URL and then use $_GET to determine the src of your iframe ... Do you have an example of your site somewhere ?

Comment: Yes, the site is www.twoboysrockin.ca.  You will see that the repeating footer contains the four links.  I just want users to click on any of those and get the portfolio page with that specific file appearing in the iframe.

Comment: Now I understand what you are trying to accomplish ... Answer updated :)

Comment: Wow, and that's EXACTLY what I needed.  I will get enormous use from this, and I really appreciate your expertise.  BTW, is there a way for visitors to browse to the iframe page (without following a link) and have the iframe default to a particular item?  From my test of the code you've kindly provided, there is only a blank iframe when the page is fetched in this way.  A second question is if I use the PHP method, which I haven't yet tried, on which page would the PHP snippet go?

Comment: I've updated the JS example, to set a default src, if there is no show=something in the URL... The PHP example was already made to set a default page, if nothing else is specified. The PHP code should go on your portfolio.php somewhere before your iframe - I'd probably place somewhere in the top ;)

Comment: Dang, that's a thing of beauty.  And so small.  Thanks again, sincerely.

Comment: You're welcome ... Please remember to check it as correct answer :)

Comment: Well, I've now scoured this page for at least five minutes.  I can't find a place to mark this as the correct answer.